# Google Chrome doesn't sync all extensions, but some of them

Tags: google-chrome, sync, google-chrome-extensions

After installing a new Google Chrome on the new system, seems it doesn't sync all of my extensions and just load some of them in new Chrome.

There are 48 extensions on my Google dashboard but only 31 of them are now in the Chrome.

Anyway to refresh local extension list manually?

Comment: Which ones exactly? Sure that these are extensions and not userscripts?

Comment: @slhck Actually I don't remember all the rest of extensions that didn't sync but for example one of them was "Delicious Bookmark". Also I have a Theme that synced every time I installed new Chrome and apply to it, But It doesn't be synced this time too. a List of my local extensions that have been synced till now is here:  http://pastebin.com/1LQYDfT4 .I couldn't find my extensions list on the Google cloud to put here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for some time. I encountered the same problem few days back. During my second login I got all of my extensions without any failure. They all will sync one by one.